# When can I omit “for” before a time duration?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

> Do not watch television [for] more than one hour a day.

Is omitting the “for” okay or is that grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *for* can be omitted in that context. “More than one hour a day” is a time duration, which generally require *for*. However, phrases beginning with *more than*, *less than*, or *fewer than* often omit *for*. I have the impression that omitting *for* in such contexts is more common in British English than in American. But when in doubt, include it.

> I talked on the phone **for two hours.**
>   I talked on the phone **(for) more than two hours.**