# When can you leave out the word "for" in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions, adverbials, measure-phrases

When can you leave the word "for" out of a sentence?

Examples:

1. They have been married ten years.
2. They have not had a holiday for ten years.

I have searched for an answer to this question, but Bing, Google and Duckduckgo don't recognize *for* as a search term but as a filler word.

Comment: This may be related but less in-depth: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60566/when-can-i-omit-for-before-a-time-duration

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin We keep having to explain to non-native speakers of English that in certain English predicates, noun phrases serving as measure phrases of time can sometimes function as adverbial adjuncts without any preposition whatsoever, but I can't find the canonical duplicate. “I waited **five minutes**.  I bet we answered this sort of question **just last week**, and I imagine we'll answer it **a week from now** as well.” And forevermore. :)

Comment: @tchrist But which ones?

Comment: [Is the 'live' in 'he only lived a few days after the accident' intrasitive or transitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100837/is-the-live-in-he-only-lived-a-few-days-after-the-accident-intrasitive-or-tr/100897#100897) addresses the issue, but I'm sure that a comprehensive list of idiomatic/grammatical {[verb] + [surface NP]} pairings would be hard to find and explain. And then the negativisers must be considered.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to search in reference works than only in Google, Bing and other search sites. To regard "for" merely as a filler is incomplete and misleading. The following material is extracted from the Cambridge discussion of *for* as a preposition. It also acts as a conjunction.

In the following examples, only where I indicate *{for}* may it be removed with no corruption of meaning. This accords with a comment from tchrist, which deals with measures of time; it also applies to measures of distance, as in the Cambridge example.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)

intended to be given to
*There's a phone message for you*

having the purpose of
*the books are not for sale*

because of or as a result of something
*She did 15 years in prison for murder*

used to show an amount of time or distance
*We walked {for} miles

She's out of the office {for} a few days next week*

on the occasion of or at the time of
*What did you buy him for Christmas?*

used for comparing one thing with others of the same type
*For every two people in favour of the law there are three against*

used to say whose responsibility something is
*the driver of the other car was not responsible for her son's death*

in support of or in agreement with
*I've got nothing against change - I'm all for it*

in order to help someone
*Let me carry those bags for you*

Comment: I can go with _She's out of the office {for} a few days next week_, but not _I haven't seen her {a few} days_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A sound counter - example. I also had a similar difficulty with the fourth Cambridge example, which I did not quote: "I haven't played tennis for years". Do you think there is a general secondary rule to catch these exceptions? I can't presently contrive one.

Comment: You can go mad trying to apply rules everywhere, and if some omniscience did, there would soon be a new exception. I'd guess that papers if not books have been written on prepositional deletion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We have done the best we can. We can aspire to no more. Thanks.